# How to get a QFormLayout() next to a GLViewWidget() in a QVBoxLayout()

Tags: python, python-3.x, qwidget, pyqtgraph, pyqt6

I am trying to get a QFormLayout() next to a GLViewWidget() in a QVBoxLayout() in QMainWindow() using the below code.

However, I struggle to find out how to display both at once, I can only display one at a time.

My aim is to have something like this:

[image]

Any idea, how to achieve that?

```
import sys
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QFormLayout,\
    QLabel, QLineEdit, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIntValidator


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        first_view_widget = gl.GLViewWidget()
        second_view_widget = gl.GLViewWidget()
        third_view_widget = gl.GLViewWidget()

        central_widget = QWidget()
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(vertical_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        horizontal_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(first_view_widget)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(second_view_widget)

        params = QHBoxLayout()
        target_distance = QLabel('First row')
        distance_input = QLineEdit()
        distance_input.setText(str(100))
        only_integers = QIntValidator()
        distance_input.setValidator(only_integers)
        air_pressure = QLabel('Second row')
        pressure_input = QLineEdit()
        pressure_input.setText(str(1.01325))
        only_integers = QIntValidator()
        pressure_input.setValidator(only_integers)

        f_layout = QFormLayout()
        f_layout.addRow(target_distance, distance_input)
        f_layout.addRow(air_pressure, pressure_input)

        params.addLayout(f_layout)
        params.addWidget(third_view_widget)

        group_box = QGroupBox('Parameters')
        group_box.setLayout(params)
        vertical_layout.addWidget(group_box)
        vertical_layout.addLayout(params)
        vertical_layout.addLayout(horizontal_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: "get a QFormLayout() next to a QWidget()" -> *what* "QWidget"? You only have one, and that's the central widget, everything else just *inherits* from QWidget, and they are completely different widget types. Please clarify what you actually want to achieve. Also, consider *smarter* reference names, as using things like `v`, `vv` and `vvv` is completely pointless: it won't make your code run faster, but it **will** make reading and debugging harder, especially to those unfamiliar with your code (that's us, who should focus on solving *your problem*, not guessing to which widget `v*` refers to).

Comment: Never, *ever* underestimate namings. Unless used within a strict *scope*, name references should always be understandable at first sight. Imagine you have three children: Valerie, Victor and Vanessa. In your family you're used to call them `v1`, `v2` and `v3`. Then you call their school because Vanessa is sick, and you tell them "my daughter, v3, is sick". They'll ask you to which child are you referring to. Then you call another a month later, as Victor is sick then: they have thousands of children, and will ask you again who `v2` is, as they can't obviously remember your "naming convention".

Comment: We are that school: we see thousands of questions, and we barely know you and your habits. We just need to tell the teachers that "v" is ill, and in the meantime we have lots of other things on our minds. But it doesn't end there. Suppose (let's hope not ;-) ) you end your marriage, and a couple of decades without reaching out with those V's and having other children; one of those V's calls you back. "Hi dad, it's vvv!". [Gosh, this isn't Victor! Wait...] "Hi Valerie!" "...dad, I'm Vanessa :-/ ". That's you, reading back your program, months after writing it, and not having a clue about it.

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly. The code is simplified as much as possible in order to demonstrate the problem. Also the picture is quite self explanatory in terms of describing what the aim is.

Comment: Add `stretch=1` to `params.addLayout` and `params.addWidget`. Also remove `vertical_layout.addLayout(params)` because that layout is already set for the groupbox. Finally, always check example code in order to verify its reproducibility: your current code would raise a few name errors because you used local variables like `first_view_widget` instead of the instance attributes created before such as `self.first_view_widget`.